# Big int values from oracle sql database become negative after reading sql in df with pandas

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I have some big numbers like `12341567899` in oracle database in `column1`. I use `python` to read the data to df.

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

after this I get my int values as negative ones. I understand that the problem is with dtype int overflow, so i tried to write `to_char(column1)` and get all big numbers as strings. But this makes my query very slow. How can I deal with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? `sys.maxsize` returns `9223372036854775807` for me.

Comment: I am using python 3.6.2

Comment: I would recommend running Python in 64-bit. 32-bit Python returns `sys.maxsize` as `2147483647`, this is where you're running into errors.

Comment: I have 64-bit python. sys.maxsize returns `9223372036854775807`

Comment: I suppose you're using `connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/pwd@DBdns:1521/DBsid')`, aren't you ..?